# Two-way ANOVA test in R

Tags: r, anova, missing-data, biostatistics, two-way

I have some measurements of 14 animals in control group and 12 animals in treatment group (10 weeks old). After 4 weeks we repeated those measurements but most of animals have died. I left with 5 animals in control group and 6 animals in treatment group (14 weeks old).

I would like to run a two-way ANOVA in R but I am not sure how to define this in my model. I performed a two-sample t-test to check the difference between the control and treated animals at 10 weeks and 14 weeks respectively. I would also like to see if the age makes a difference. So I would like to perform a two-way ANOVA for treatment group and age rather than separate t-test.

My sample are unbalanced, I have 10 control animals and 10 treated but after the 4 weeks I left with 4 controls and 5 treated.

I performed the two-way ANOVA in R but I have a question in the interpretation of the results. I can see where the group or the age are significant but I can't tell if the group is significant at 10 weeks or at 14 weeks. The R output is shown below. I can see that the group is significant but how do I know if it's significant at both 10 and 14 weeks or only at 10 or 14 weeks?

```
    Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value  Pr(>F)    
age          1    994     994   2.922  0.0993 .  
group        1   7906    7906  23.238 5.4e-05 ***
Residuals   26   8846     340
```

Does it make sense to use two-sample t-test as a sub analysis to check if the difference in group is significant at 10 or 14 weeks?

Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: Are the dead subject relevant? If yes, you might want to check for survival analyses.

Comment: Can you provide more information about the specific R command you're using? There are many ways to run an ANOVA in R which vary in how SS are computed: `lm()` vs. `anova()` v. `aov()`, e.g.

Comment: I am used the aov() function although I am not sure if I did it correct. I used my.anova<-aov(measurements~age+group). I have unbalanced groups. I also wonder what is the difference if I use my.anova<-aov(measurements~age*group)

Comment: What is your research question ? This does not seem like a two-way Anova because age is presumably numeric, not categorical. Also, you have repeated measures which have to be accounted for, along with time.

Comment: @RobertLong Age is numerical but I made it categorical in order to perform the ANOVA test. Like putting 1 for 10 weeks measurements and 2 for 14 weeks measurements. I am trying to see if there are differences in the measurements between the control and treated group. But I would also like to know if there are changes between the two ages for each group. Would it be better to use two-sample t-test and look for differences between the two groups and the two ages?